# Not able to download a file through request in python

Tags: python, download, request

When I try to download a file online it doesn't work for a particular site while it works for others. Why is this happening and what should I do about it?

I write the content of the dl request in my case https://drivers.amd.com/drivers/amd-software-adrenalin-edition-22.11.1-win10-win11-nov15.exe (**warning**: 500+ MB file) from this page: https://www.amd.com/fr/support/graphics/amd-radeon-6000-series/amd-radeon-6900-series/amd-radeon-rx-6900-xt

```py
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

web = Session()
web.headers.update(headers)

def dl_btn(self):
        try:
            dl = web.get(self.link) #I use an old session that allowed me to retrieve a download link.
            file = dl.headers['Content-Disposition'].split('=')[1]
            file = filedialog.askdirectory() + '/' + file #Open file explorer to choose the download destination.
            open(file, "wb").write(dl.content)
        except:
            popen(f'start {self.link}') #It open a page that indicate me a wrong request...
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example; we don't know wht `web` etc are and cannot run your code. What errors are you getting?

Comment: @kwinkunks I just updated my code, replace self.link by my link provided in comment and it should work (returning the error of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [error page](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/download-incomplete), it tells you exactly what the problem is: they don't allow downloads without a referer from their website. Therefore, your headers will need to include a [`Referer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) key/value, and I assume a proper `User-Agent` as well:

```
import requests
from tkinter import filedialog

referer = "https://www.amd.com/fr/support/graphics/amd-radeon-6000-series/amd-radeon-6900-series/amd-radeon-rx-6900-xt"
file_to_dl = "https://drivers.amd.com/drivers/amd-software-adrenalin-edition-22.11.1-win10-win11-nov15.exe"
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
headers = {"User-Agent": user_agent,
           "Referer": referer}

r = requests.get(file_to_dl, headers=headers)
# wait a while...
file = file_to_dl.split("/")[-1]
file_location = filedialog.askdirectory() + '/' + file
open(file_location, "wb").write(r.content)
```

Comment: Hello, I just tried to add a referer it seems to load something: it loads for a while then the error comes back... I found a way to fix it by removing the dl.headers exploit, why isn't there the file's title in the headers?

Comment: I don't know why the file's name isn't in the headers in this method, but as you'll notice in my code I removed checking for `Content-Disposition` and instead took the file's name from the download URL. My code works perfectly fine when I run it. That's why I put it all there, instead of just changing a line or two of your original code.